# Book recommendation to 8-year old non-native girl

Tags: primary-schooler, reading, books

I would like to ask you for advice.

What book would you recommend to my 8-year old daughter?

I'm trying to teach her reading. We are not natives but she can speak fluently. She has read all Ladybird Tales quite easily so I bought her "The Incorrigible Children of Ashton Place" - which looked like a very nice book but she doesn't like it. The flowery language and the lack of a real story (at least at the beginning) are too much for her.

She would like something more filled with a story, more straight, preferably with animals. Does anybody have any advice - a book you liked or a book your kids like?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried Diary of a Wimpy Kid?

Comment: Is this sort of recommendation question on topic? In general, these sorts of questions aren't a good match for Stack Exchange's question and answer format, because there typically isn't a single objectively correct answer.

Comment: 2 Jan: Thanks. It looks great, simple words to read but I'm a little bit worried about text "font" - this hand-written text is not so easy to read. But all the rest is great. I will try it. Thanks

Comment: 2 nick012000: Yes, it is a recommendation question. I'm sorry, I just didn't know where to aks and I felt like a "parenting" forum would be appropriate. If it is against rules I'm sorry, it was not on purpose.

Comment: Yorik, welcome! I see what you are trying to do and as a parent I think helping you child learn (and love) to read is wonderful. As a moderator, I’m sorry but this kind of question is opinion-based and I must close it. The [tour] and the [help] will explain more about it.

Comment: Keep trying. Spend some time in a library. Try different books. Can you read to her? A bed time story read by a parent is a special time in its own right, and if you leave the story at a cliff hanger you may find her picking it up to read ahead.

Comment: E.B. White's Charlotte's Web. A story of a little girl, a pig and a spider. Award winning novel, kids love it. https://www.amazon.com/Charlottes-Web-B-White/dp/0061124958

Comment: @Yorik I had good luck with books for some of the "Best of" lists, please see a few examples at the end of [my answer to a related question](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/a/41170/33055). Good luck! I wish your question stayed open, I am interested in other answers.

Comment: @Yorik Another [previous answer](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/a/37739/33055)